# Change format of XML file in clover ETL

Tags: xml, type-conversion, clover, cloveretl

I'm running a graph using clover ETL to convert a CSV file into XML output (it uses XML writer). However, when I open the XML output file (just in notepad) it is all written on a single line such that the file is difficult to read. Is there a setting I can use to tell XML writer how I want my output file to look?

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure what version you use, but in latest versions XMLWriter has attribute "*Omit new lines*" (`omitNewLine`), which is most likely enabled in your graph. Although the attribute should be turned off by default, you may explicitly set it to false (`omitNewLines="false"`) in order to make sure each element will be written on a separate line.

Hope it helps.